Stuck on Game Theory Question

You and your friend play a game where you both select an integer $1 - 100$. The winner receives $1$ from the loser. The winner is the player
who selects the strictly higher number. If there is a tie, then
nothing happens. However, a player can also win by selecting a value
exactly $2$ below the larger integer. For example, if you select $80$
and your friend selects $82$, you are the winner in this case. Assume
both you and your friend play optimally. What is the optimal strategy?

I am stuck here. Clearly you want to choose a high number since higher numbers beat more things. You also want a mixed strategy because if you choose a single number, $x$, all the time, the opponent will just pick $x-2$. I was considering a mixed strategy of picking 98 and 100 with equal probability. Any ideas?

Your  mixed strategy will not do well if I play $98$ all the time.

this is a near duplicate.

Notice that you never need to play a number less than 98. If you are tempted to play an $x$ less than 98, just play $x+3$ instead, and your outcome will be at least as good.

@NicholasBurbank writing down the payoff table for ${98,99,100}\times {98,99,100}$ makes it easy to spot the Nash equilibrium/minimax/maximin strategy

I'm going to assume that both players play simultaneously, but here is what I think is optimal:
The best numbers to pick are 100, 99 and 98. This is because 100 beats 99 beats 98 beats 100. This boils down to the optimal strategy being picking one of these with an equal probability of 1/3. (Basically rock paper scissors).
Also, I think a similar question has been answered before and I'm just adapting a solution.
